# jQuery .html() does not select some emails?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am starting to use jQuery and when I try to select the content inside a div, some emails don't get selected? I'm using Safari's console to execute the jQuery code. I get the desired result with `.text()` but why doesn't `.html()` work?

**jQuery**

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").parents('.organizer_listing').find('.organizer_listing_contact_email')
```

**Result**

```
[
<div class=​"organizer_listing_contact_email">​ciara@bhre.net​</div>​
, 
<div class=​"organizer_listing_contact_email">hihi-p38sn-2788580457@somewhere.org​</div>​
, 
<div class=​"organizer_listing_contact_email">hihi-2xxtn-2783323299@someowhere.org​</div>​
]
```

**jQuery**

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").parents('.organizer_listing').find('.organizer_listing_contact_email').html()
```

**Result**

```
"ciara@bhre.net"
```

Comment: .html() can only return a string. It cannot return an array of strings

Comment: The docs are your friend here: http://api.jquery.com/html/ `html()`: `Description: Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accessor methods (most of which can be mutators too, but anyway) will only work on the first item in the result set.

That is, `.html()` will give you the html of the first item in the set, just as `.attr('href')` will give you the first item's `href` attribute.

Instead, you might want to use [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
...find('.organizer_listing_contact_email').map(function () {
    return $(this).html();
}).get();
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) return a *collection* of jQuery objects. You need iterate over the elements in that collection. You could use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to do that:

```
var $emails = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").parents('.organizer_listing').find('.organizer_listing_contact_email');

$emails.each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```